# Trouble with making python rearrange code to my wanted format. (Python 3.6)

Tags: python

So basically I want python to first wait and let me input stuff and then do whatever it has to for every pair of inputs.

```
t = int(input())
E = 0
for i in range(0, t):
    M, N = [int(M) for M in input(" ").split()]
    if E in range(0, t):
        if M > 0 and N > 0:
            print("X")
        if M > 0 and N == 0:
            print("Y")
        if M == 0 and N > 0:
            print("Z")
        i += 1
```

The terminal looks somewhat like this,

```
13 100
X
 2 0
 Y
```

I want the 2 0 to be before X but at the same time I want the code to calculate for 13 100 and output X but just after I input the 2nd pair of X, Y.

I also want to know how to remove the spaces before the '2 0' and the 'Y'.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the purpose of `E` in the code?

Comment: Also what is the purpose of `i`?

Comment: The space before your inputs comes from your input prompt `input(" ")`. There is no space before `Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the reason you have spaces before 2 0 is because in the line:

```
 M, N = [int(M) for M in input(" ").split()]
```

your input function has a space within the quotes, so you must remove it and just have an empty string:

```
 M, N = [int(M) for M in input("").split()]
```

Next, the reason your code is asking for input then generating an output and so on is because the logical operators are within the for loop you have. To fix this you should have your loop to first gather the inputs then, have another loop to perform the logical operators on those inputs as so:

```
t = 2
E = 0

numList = []

for i in range(0, t):
    M, N = [int(M) for M in input("").split()]

    numList.append([M, N])

for val in numList:
    if E in range(0, t):
        if val[0] > 0 and val[1] > 0:
            print("X")
        if val[0] > 0 and val[1] == 0:
            print("Y")
        if val[0] == 0 and val[1] > 0:
            print("Z")
```

To simplify things I set t = 2 since we are only talking about 2 pairs of numbers. Furthermore, I created a list to hold each pair of inputs (numList), in which the first for loop appends the values to it as an list. The next for loop looks at each item in numList and since numList is a list of lists I changed M and N to val[0] and val[1] which refer to the first number you inputed (M) and the second one you inputed (N).

Finally,

```
for i in range(0, t):
```

should look like:

```
for i in range(t):
```

Since the range function automatically just counts from 0 to t and "i += 1" at the end of the loop is also unnecessary and redundant.

My final output:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bo9U.png

Comment: What does 
M, N = [int(M) for M in input("").split()]
do?

Comment: you tell me, you're the one who wrote it

Answer (score 0):

Put all the inputs in a 2-dimensional list before the loop that processes them.

```
t = int(input())
E = 0
all_inputs = [[int(M) for M in input(" ").split()] for _ in range(t)]

for M, N in all_inputs:
    if E in range(0, t):
        if M > 0 and N > 0:
            print("X")
        if M > 0 and N == 0:
            print("Y")
        if M == 0 and N > 0:
            print("Z")
        i += 1
```

The space before the `2 0` is the prompt `" "` in your `input(" ")` call. If you don't want that, use `input()` with no prompt.

I don't see any reason for the space before `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help. Its a little cleaned up:

```
iterations = int(input("How many times? "))

values = []
for i in range(iterations):
    values.append([int(M) for M in input(f"{i+1}. Enter two numbers: ").split()])
    
for M, N in values:
    print(M, N, end=' -> ')
    if M > 0 and N > 0:
        print("X")
    if M > 0 and N == 0:
        print("Y")
    if M == 0 and N > 0:
        print("Z")
```